# Decision problem: Existence of a perfect number m larger than a natural number n

Tags: perfect-numbers, decision-problems

I am currently having a look at the slides from my theoretical computer science lecture and I am having trouble to understand a claim made. According to the slides the language

$L = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} ~|~ \exists~ m: m > n \wedge \text{m is a perfect number} \}$

is decidable even though the total number of perfect numbers is unknown.

Obviously L is semi-decidable as one can start searching for a perfect number $> n$. If there is no such number the algorithmn will never terminate, resulting in the semi-decidability of $L$.

My question would be if there is a different approach allowing to decide $L$, i. e.  the algorithmn also terminates when $n \not\in L$ or if the claim made is incorrect.

### Edit: Solution (thanks to ToniK and Peter)

$L$ is either finite (if there is a largest perfect number) or equal to $\mathbb{N}$ (if the set of perfect numbers is infinite). By sticking to the definition of decidability one only needs to proof that **there is** an algorithm deciding whether a concrete $n \in L$ or not. **We do not need to provide an algorithm for that - this is just an existential proof.** In either case one can decide $L$ (as $L$ is finite or $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: This comes from the weird definition of "decidable". This leads to the situation that we can decide every SINGLE statement because either the algorithm that always returns false gives the correct answer or the algorithm that always returns true. Here, the algorithm makes use of the largest perfect number in the case there are finite many. So, by the definition of "deciable" , $L$ is actually decidable. The catch in practice would be that we would not be able to actually find the largest perfect number.

Comment: Sometimes one can show that $L$ is decidable by showing that both $L$ and its complement are semi-decidable, but that doesn't seem useful here.

Comment: @Peter The problem is trivial if there would be a proof whether there is a largest perfect number (i. e. the set of perfect numbers is finite). If this is the case one can decide $L$ by comparing $n$ to the largest perfect number. If the set is infinite $L = \mathbb{N}$. But this is yet an open problem...

Comment: @Skrillor In theory, we can do that. In practice, the algorithm would fail even in the case we would have a non-constructed proof that there are only finite many perfect numbers. We still would never know whether we have found the largest (with which we would compare $n$) , or whether there would still be a larger one.

Comment: The situation is not the same as in the case of Goldbach's conjecture. If this conjecture is false, then we can show this in finite time by finding the smallest counterexample. But determining the largest perfect number (if there is a largest) would be another thing.

Comment: @Peter: it's not such a weird definition. The primary concept is not decidablilty, but undecidability; and it is quite natural to define an undecidable set $L$ as one for which no algorithm can determine membership of $L$. So decidability is a derived concept; the decidable sets are just those sets that are not undecidable.

Comment: Your solution comes from posts by Peter and me. In such cases it is customary to include an acknowledgment.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry for that - the edit was supposed to wrap up all the comments and answers made. I falsely assumed that this would be obvious right away. I have added the acknowledgment and I will in the future. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ is decidable because it is either finite, or the whole of $\Bbb N$. We just don't know which.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. It is not *decidable* unless you have a way to *decide* whether a concrete $n$ belongs to it or not.

Comment: @OlivierRoche: A set $L$ is decidable if there exists an algorithm for determining membership of $L$. Here there clearly _exists_ such an algorithm; therefore $L$ is decidable, by definition. The fact that we don't currently know  how to _program_ this algorithm is perhaps unfortunate, but it assuredly exists.

Comment: @OlivierRoche: Presumably you read Peter's comment to the OP before posting your own. Did you simply not understand it?

Comment: I understood your (and Pete's) argument perfectly, but I think it has a flaw : what if the statement "$L$ is infinite" is independent from ZFC?

Comment: @OlivierRoche: you think it has a flaw. This is a long way from "just plain wrong". (Spoiler alert: it doesn't have a flaw.)

Comment: @TonyK I finally got your point, seems to be flawless. Most proofs involve the concrete algorithm deciding the language but here we can only say that there is such an algorithm as L is either finite or $\mathbb{N}$. The algorithm depends on which of the two statements is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyK Well, you were right all along. I saw ghosts where it was as easy as you told. Well done.

Comment: Why can’t the existence of infinitely many perfect numbers be independent (of whatever other axioms are being assumed in the problem)?